# NodeJS - create express server on button click event

Tags: node.js, express

I'm beginner to Node, I just need to create a express server on a button click event, I did as below but it shouldn't work

**script.js**

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $.post('/test');
});
```

**app.js**

```
app.post('/test', function (req, res) {

    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
       res.send('Hello World');
    })

    var server = app.listen(3100, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port 
  })
});
```

Comment: Why do you need that... ?

Comment: Do you actually have a server running in the first place?

Comment: I need to create a separate server, so it should run two servers at same time

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? 

Above implementation has a problem - when you hit the button a server will get created listening on 3100 port. When you hit the button again it will give you error because the port 3100 is already taken.

Comment: I have a running server on port 3000, I need to create a separate server on port 3100